# jQuery get & replace html in radio input to add label tag

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working with a content management system so I DO NOT have direct HTML access (would be much easier if I did!)

Through JQuery I need to add an id tag to each radio button based on the radio button's value & add a class & label tag. Here's the HTML:

```
<span class="product_code">TESTPRODUCT</span> 
<br /> 
<table> 
  <td valign="top"></td>
  <td> 
    <input name="SELECT___TESTPRODUCT___13" value="5" type="radio" > Size 5<br />
    <input name="SELECT___TESTPRODUCT___13" value="6" type="radio"> Size 6<br />
    <input name="SELECT___TESTPRODUCT___13" value="7" type="radio"> Size 7<br />

  </td> 
</table>
```

and here's my jQuery attempt:

```
var productCode = $(".product_code").text();
var WidthRadioValue = $('input[name="SELECT___' + productCode + '___13"]').val();
var $nodes = $('input[name="SELECT___' + productCode + '___13"]').contents();
var label = '<label for="' + this.id + '">' + nextNode.textContent + '</label>';
var nextNode = $nodes[i + 1];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:radio[name="SELECT___' + productCode + '___13"]').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('WidthRadioClass');
    $('input[name="SELECT___' + productCode + '___13"]').attr("id", WidthRadioValue + "mm");

  });

  $nodes.each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).is('input')) {
      if (nextNode && nextNode.nodeType == 3) {
        $(nextNode).replaceWith('<label for="' + this.id + '">' + nextNode.textContent + '</label>');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Ultimately, I need the HTML to look like this:

```
<span class="product_code">TESTPRODUCT</span> 
<br /> 
<table> 
  <td valign="top"></td>
  <td> 
    <input id="5mm" class="WidthRadioClass" name="SELECT___TESTPRODUCT___13" value="5" type="radio" /> 
    <label for="5mm">Size 5</label>

    <input id="6mm" class="WidthRadioClass" name="SELECT___TESTPRODUCT___13" value="6" type="radio" />
    <label for="6mm">Size 6</label>

    <input id="7mm" class="WidthRadioClass" name="SELECT___TESTPRODUCT___13" value="7" type="radio" /> 
    <label for="7mm">Size 7</label>

  </td> 
</table>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What CMS is that? This looks like trying to hack your way around a small modification because you're unfamiliar with the HTML generator behind it.

Comment: shopping cart Volusion. Yes I'm trying to hack my way around a small modification because I literally have no HTML access for this section

Comment: Alright fair enough. Is `<input><label></label>` the only output that is acceptable, or can you work with `<label><input></label>` ? Just asking as that one might be more intuitive here.

Comment: I'll need to style it, I've not styled radio buttons with the input inside the label before, I'm open to giving it a shot but I'm not 100% certain it'll work. The radio buttons will eventually look like buttons (no the CMS doesn't have generator for buttons for this section, yes the CMS REALLY SUCKS)

Comment: I can see why you ended up with this question now. :D Bad CMSs are bad. Found a way around the inputs being nested in labels at last!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the snippet below or see this **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/OxmMzo)**

```js
// list of radio input elements
var els = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');

// loop through radio input elements
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  // clear text
  els[i].nextSibling.nodeValue = '';
  // create new elements
  var val = els[i].value,
    label = document.createElement("label");

  label.setAttribute("for", val + "mm");
  label.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Size " + val))

  els[i].id = val + "mm";
  els[i].insertAdjacentElement("afterend", label);
}
```

```html
<span class="product_code">TESTPRODUCT</span>
<br>
<table>
  <td valign="top"></td>
  <td>
    <input name="SELECT___TESTPRODUCT___13" value="5" type="radio"> Size 5<br>
    <input name="SELECT___TESTPRODUCT___13" value="6" type="radio"> Size 6<br>
    <input name="SELECT___TESTPRODUCT___13" value="7" type="radio"> Size 7<br>
  </td>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks Dan, the id is being created properly (which is awesome!) but no label tag around the text :(

Comment: @KateTheGreat - Whoops - it's fixed now :) I've updated the CodePen and the snippet above. I feel your pain with the CMS stuff by the way.

Comment: You, sir, are amazing! Thank you so much :) I appreciate the CMS commiseration too, its downright demoralizing sometimes!

Answer (score 1):

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eq80z1kL/) has you covered. Basically, you can grab the HTML as plain text, split it along the `<br>`s, pad them with `<label></label>` and inject it back into the container. From there you can access the attributes and IDs through jQuery and can avoid having to change node types around and all that.

To work around the inputs being nested in the labels, you can use jQuery's `insertBefore()` method while iterating to move the inputs outside their respective labels.

```
var $cell = $('td:nth-of-type(2)'),
    lines = $cell.html().split('<br>');

// wrap the split lines in labels
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    if (lines[i].length > 2) {
        lines[i] = '<label>'+lines[i]+'</label>';
    }
}

// join back together and inject html
$cell.html(lines.join(''));

// do the fiddling with ids
$cell.find('label').each(function(i) {
    var $this = $(this),
        $input = $this.find('input'),
        value = $input.val();
  $this.attr('for', value+'mm');
  $input.attr('id', value+'mm');
  $input.insertBefore($this)
})
```